# How to implement a calendar event-driven workflow in Java

Tags: java, spring, events, calendar, timed

The project I work in requires me to write a service in Java that acts as a calendar. It should be possible to put events on the calendar, at a specific point in time.

And there should be a process that checks if the time has come to execute the event.

I am thinking of using a database that has a table of events, by timestamp. One process puts the events in the database (or updates existing events, which must be possible), and then the other process periodically checks if it is time to execute the event.

However, I wonder if API's or frameworks already exist to achieve this?

I am using Spring in our projects.

Answer (score -1):

Very quickly after posting the question, I have found Spring Quartz API. This may be what I was looking for.